# Can't get controls to work for my Tetris game

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a lot of trouble getting my controls to work for my game I have tried several different ways and nothing seems to work.
This is what I have currently with two different layers in visual studio.
1st- part

```
class Moves
    {
        public bool rightKeyPressed { get; set; }
        public bool leftKeyPressed { get; set; }

        public Moves()
        {
            rightKeyPressed = false;
            leftKeyPressed = false;
        }

        public void evaluateKey(Keys key, Boolean pressed)
        {
            if (key == Keys.Left)
                leftKeyPressed = pressed;
            else if (key == Keys.Right)
                rightKeyPressed = pressed;
        }
    }
```

2nd part

```
private void frmMain_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (playing)
    {
        if (input.leftKeyPressed)
            GameField.moveCurrentShapeLeft();
        if (input.rightKeyPressed)
            GameField.moveCurrentShapeRight();
        this.updateGameBoard();
    }
    input.evaluateKey(e.KeyCode, false);
}

    private void frmMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && playing)
            input.evaluateKey(e.KeyCode, true); e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: From the code you posted, nothing should happen.  A Space bar is pressed, which won't set any of the left or right keys pressed, so nothing happens.  Is the `e.Handled = true;` supposed to be a part of the `if {...}` block?  Because it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

In your frmMain_KeyDown, you are only calling input.evaluateKey() if e.KeyCode == Keys.Space.  You'll never handle a left or right key that way.  Remove that clause from the if.